# Values are not being added in Excel file using PHPExcel in yii

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I'm trying to export data to Excel file using PHPExcel in yii. But I'm getting blank cells when I try to export data to excel file.

I'm able to add static values in the file such as column names.

```
    $rowCount = 2; 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, "Sr. No");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, "Suite Name");
```

this is the code in my controller action. I can see array values with that echo statement.

```
         $i = 1;
   $rowCount = 3; 
    foreach ($result as $row) {
         $value =  $row['suite_name'];
        echo "<javascript type='text/javascript'>alert('$i, $rowCount, C$rowCount, D$rowCount ".$value."')</script>"; 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $i); 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $value); 
        // Increment the Excel row counter
        $rowCount++; 
        $i++;
    }
```

instead of $value I tried directly with $row['suite_name'], that didn't worked either. Please, Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHPExcel fromArray() method for saving array values to excel sheet.

### Example

single dimensional array

```
$rowArray = array('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray(
        $rowArray,   // The data to set
        NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
        'C3'         // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                     //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
    );
```

Multi dimensional array

```
$arrayData = array(
    array(NULL, 2010, 2011, 2012),
    array('Q1',   12,   15,   21),
    array('Q2',   56,   73,   86),
    array('Q3',   52,   61,   69),
    array('Q4',   30,   32,    0),
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray(
        $arrayData,  // The data to set
        NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
        'C3'         // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                     //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
);
```

Comment: Try using fromArray() method and let me know whether it is working.

Comment: It's not working...  I think the statement is not getting executed.. dont know why. neither first one nor yours..

Comment: If the values are written to excel while you are making the function call with manual values, then you should check your array elements and array parsing part of the code.

Comment: ya, checked that too, array values are displaying correctly. I think these two statements / one you mentioned isn't getting executed inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Try creating a single dimensional array with only 'suite_name' and write it to excel just outside foreach loop with the example given in my answer.

Comment: I tried that too, can you tell me how to check if the statement, $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rowArray,NULL,'C3');

is executed or not?

Comment: try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); in your script and check if you are getting any errors. use PHP die() function to check whether your function call has been successful or not. Also check this documentation for further clarifications ( https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md )